# How to set form size to exact screen dimensions on android?

Tags: android, delphi

I'd like to have a form have the exact same dimensions as the screen size for my android app. Since I couldn't figure it out what I've done so far is create a `tLayout` as parent-most component on my form, put everything in it, and used:

```
if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService (IFMXScreenService, IInterface(ScreenService)) then begin
 antiscale := 1/ScreenService.GetScreenScale;
 layout1.Scale.X:=antiscale;
 layout1.Scale.Y:=antiscale;
end;
```

in my `form1.FormCreate` to scale everything in my `tLayout` back to actual screen coordinates. This works on the androids I've tried but seems pretty suboptimal and I'd like to learn a better way to do this. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

If you place eveything on your form in a TScaledLayout and align that as Client, it adjusts all the components to fit on your android screen.

I made my forms 400 wide by 712 high which seemed to scale OK on various recent Android phones (Samsung Galaxy S5/6, Sony Xperia Z2)